# Writing REST Web service client

Tags: c++, rest

I would to create a client to access a REST web service in C++.
This should include authentication and session management. Writing this entirely from scratch is big task. Is there any helper library / framework available? Any example / tutorial would help me? I heard of libcurl and for framework STAFF. But not sure how STAFF generates the code and whether it is specific to Apache.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a PAM module that uses libcurl, but you could easily adapt it for your needs:

[Pam-http](https://github.com/beatgammit/pam-http).

Just look at the headers and functions I use. I use SSL as well, so this is a pretty complete example.

Comment: Just a note. This is written in C, but there is no issue with using it in C++ code.

Comment: Then you may need to adjust me makefile to link in libcurl (and possibly build it). It should work on Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can go with C, you can use Axis2 C -

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/

or

http://wso2.org/project/wsf/cpp/2.0.0/docs/